# sysinfo struct in linux/kernel.h

Tags: c, linux, header, kernel

I was snooping around looking at various kernel header files and stumbled across `<linux/kernel.h>`. Inside it is a structure called `sysinfo`.

I've tried using it out of the box so to speak and all the values in the structure returned 0. Im guessing I need to use the poplating function above called `do_sysinfo(struct sysinfo *info)`.

The thing is I can't find any info which references how to use it. I tried the function out of the box and it failed because it couldn't be linked. Anyone have any information about how to use this or why it's failing? I am a newbie in this area. Would like any links to good guides/info if you have them, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you tried to call that function from userspace. That is not possible, since that header is for kernel use only, except for the struct sysinfo that is "shared".

You probably want to use the system call `int sysinfo(struct sysinfo *info)` by including `sys/sysinfo.h` in order to populate the `struct sysinfo`.

Answer (score 4):

`do_sysinfo` is the kernel-side implementation; it's not accessible from userland. The `sysinfo` system call is accessible, though; it's what populates the structure:

```
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

...

struct sysinfo info;
sysinfo(&info);
```

Note that there's much more information available by parsing files in `/proc` (e.g, `/proc/uptime`, `/proc/cpuinfo`, `/proc/meminfo`).

Comment: Firstly, thank you all for answering my question. Huge help! Seriously though. Where do you all learn this stuff? That kind of knowledge is nowhere to be found on the web. Its a pain to find out these little details. Any links to cool stuff?

Comment: @A.Smith https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/meminfo.c